# why it is not recommended to use e.printstacktrace() by sonar?

Tags: java, exception, sonarqube

i recently started using sonar as code review tool.
When i analysed my code running sonar,
it reflected printing stack trace as violation of java coding standard.
As an alternative to stack trace, I tried:

```
e.getcause()
```

but this did not clear the exception as done by stack trace

Comment: It's *critical* that the code detail in your title/question reflect *exact* characters - you're clearly missing capitalization.  So that we aren't working on ambiguous assumptions please correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Error handling can be tricky in any environment, java included.  I haven't used sonar, but I can comment on general good practices for java error handling.

e.printStackTrace() is generally discouraged because it just prints out the stack trace to standard error.  Because of this you can't really control where this output goes.

The better thing to do is to use a logging framework (logback, slf4j, java.util.logging, log4j, etc) because then you can control where the errors are logged to and what the log retention policy is.

And generally you'll want to catch the exception and if it's unexpected behavior, log it and either throw a new exception (probably specific to your application) or do whatever you have to do to continue operating gracefully.

If you're using java.util.logging, you can do something like the following:

```
class YourClass
{
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(YourClass.class.getName());

...

public void someMethod() throws YourException
{
  try
  {
    // your code here
  } catch (NullPointerException e)
  {
    String message = "Unexpected NullPointerException in processing!";
    logger.log(Level.ERROR, message, e);

    throw new YourException(message, e);
  }
}

}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Level.ERROR doesn't exist, you might be thinking about SEVERE http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Level.html

Comment: Note that it is generally advisable to either log the exception OR rethrow it, but not both. One of the main reasons is that it is almost impossible for the next class in the call hierarchy to determine whether the exception has already been logged. This will inevitably lead to extra work - namely hunting down double & triple log entries.

Answer (score 0):

A few thoughts:

1. I presume from the title you were using `e.printStackTrace()`.  This does **not** "clear the exception", so I'm not sure exactly what your issue really is on that point.  In java "clear the exception" doesn't make any sense at all in this context.
2. `e.printStackTrace()` is "not a good idea" because it writes to standard out.  Much better to write such detail to a log file for later diagnostics, rather than put it out in front of a user (though that could depend on how the program actually runs).  Your run-time environment may have something to say about use of standard output.
3. `e.getCause()` will return, if available, an "underlying exception" that may have been a "root cause" for the exception `e`.  Must stack traces will show this after an initial stack dump denoted by "Caused by: : ..."
4. If you choose to try to capture and display/log an exception yourself - you might use `e.printStackTrace(PrintStream s)` or `e.printStackTrace(PrintWriter s)`.
5. You'd be best served using a logging tool, as suggested by Matt.

Comment: using >e.printStackTrace(PrintStram s)

Comment: If >e.printStackTrace(PrintStream s) puts the stacktrace in log file then it will be helpful to me.As i am using spring application , i have to initialize PrintStream only for putting stacktrace in logs.